# Academic Interview

Tags: learning, academic-study

My name is Aidan, I am a senior student from a small High School in Ontario, Canada. I am doing a research project on Buddhism in a world cultures class. I would like to ask practicing Buddhists some questions about the religion to learn more about Buddhism. I have attempted to contact some local Buddhist groups to ask questions, however, none have responded to me. I figured this would be a good place to try and find some practicing Buddhists. If you would be interested in helping me learn more about the religion, I would greatly appreciate any responses.

Below I have added the questions for those who would like to respond in the comments. Answer as many or as few as you’d like.

- In your opinion, how would you define the organized religion of
  ‘Buddhism’? Were there any familial expectations to become involved
  in this religion or was this a personal choice that you made? What
  does it mean to be ‘Buddhist’ to you?
- How long have you been practicing Buddhism? Has your religion been an
  influential factor in how you were raised? (Eg: have you ever been
  unable to partake in certain activities because it would compromise
  your religious beliefs/practices?) Is there a personal reason as to
  why you chose to become Buddhist?
- What are some of the customary rituals and practices related to
  Buddhism? Are prayer and meditation essential components of this
  organized religion? If so, how many times a day/week do you pray?
- In your opinion, does meditating help you obtain physical, mental and
  spiritual health?
- Are there any items that should be avoided in this life if one were
  to become a practicing Buddhist? (ex. Foods, meats, alcohol?)
- What does Buddhism suggest happens to you when you die? Is there such
  a thing as an ‘afterlife’ in Buddhism? What are your personal
  thoughts on what happens when you die?
- Hinduism and Buddhism are two of the largest religions in the world.
  Both believe in reincarnation, however, both religions are very
  different from each other. What do you think are the key factor(s)
  that differentiate the two religions?
- What do you think of the ideas of modern Atheists/Agnostics, who
  believe there is no God(s) or do not believe there is enough proof to
  determine if there is a God or not? Is the practice of Buddhism
  respectful of these ideas?
- In the future, how do you think Buddhsim will evolve moving forward
  throughout the world
- Do you think that there are any misconceptions that surround the
  organized religion of Buddhism and if so, what do you think they are?
  What solutions would you put forward to combat these misconceptions
  in Canada today and moving forward?
- How could a person go about joining/becoming a buddhist? If you
  didn’t join via your family, how did you join buddhism?
- How has COVID-19 affected how your practice buddhism?

Comment: This isn't really the best place for this, for several reasons. (1) it's quite difficult to answer a set of question like this on this forum. (2) you'll have selection bias: this site leans heavily towards deep seekers and high practice; you'll miss most of the cultural aspects of the religion. However, Ontario has [a number of decent Buddhist centers](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=buddhist+centers+ontario+canada&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8); your best bet is go to a few of them in person and ask if you can do interviews or pass out questionnaires. You'll be received well...

Comment: "Polling" questions are explicitly off-topic on SE.

Comment: Agreed with the above comments, plus I feel the list of questions is too long for someone to answer in writing in a single post.

Comment: Those are good questions for one who would be interested to get a little familar, yet of course personal raised. Thinking that good householder seeks after answers for kind of statistics doesn't inspire others much. How ever, maybe raising question one by one and try to personalize them, say not asking for opinions but from the Buddhas view.

Comment: What I don't understand, Aidan, is questions like this: "Were there any familial expectations to become involved in this religion or was this a personal choice that you made?" This is obviously a "personal" question. Why ask that kind of question? Is it idle curiosity? Collecting statistics? Trying to find a correlation between the ways in which different questions are answered?